# Renaming a file manually and then renaming in database C#

Tags: c#

I want to rename the file in the database(for file information)

It's not working when I use

```
name=Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filepath)
```

I think the problem is at `e.OldName` he still takes the old name **WITH THE EXTENSION** while in the database it's without the extension.

How can I fix that the `e.OldName` goes without the extension? Same way as I did with `e.Name`?

Ok I got this code, but it's not working:

```
  private void fileSystemWatcher1_Renamed(object sender, System.IO.RenamedEventArgs e)
    {
        filepath = Path.Combine(source, e.Name);
        oldfilepath = Path.Combine(source, e.OldName);
        Console.WriteLine(e.OldName + " => " + e.Name);
        listBox1.Items.Add("File renamed> " + e.FullPath + " -Date:" + DateTime.Now);
        name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filepath);
        oldfilename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(oldfilepath);
        extension = Path.GetExtension(e.FullPath);
        size = e.Name.Length;
        query = "update files set name='"+name+"' where name='"+oldfilename +"'";
        query();
    }

    static void query()
    {
        String database1 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[@"Database1"];
        var connection = new MySqlConnection(database1);
        connection.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
    }


        private void fileSystemWatcher1_Created(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        filepath = Path.Combine(source, e.Name );
        listBox1.Items.Add("File created> " + e.FullPath + " -Date:" + DateTime.Now);
        name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filepath);
        extension = Path.GetExtension(e.FullPath);
        size = e.Name.Length;
        query = "INSERT INTO files (name,size,last_edit,extension) VALUES('" + name + "','" + size + "',now(),'" + extension + "')";    
        query();

        if (Directory.Exists(e.FullPath))
        {
            copyfolder();
            Directory.CreateDirectory(target);
        }
        else
        {

            if (WaitForFileAvailable(e.FullPath, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)))
            {
                var file = Path.Combine(source, e.Name);
                var copy_file = Path.Combine(target, e.Name);
                var destination = Path.Combine(target, Path.ChangeExtension(source, Path.GetExtension(source)));

                if (File.Exists(file))
                {
                    File.Delete(copy_file);
                    File.Copy(e.FullPath, Path.Combine(target, e.Name));
                }
                else
                {
                    File.Copy(e.FullPath, Path.Combine(target, e.Name));
                }
            }
            else // The file failed to become available within 10 seconds.
            {
                // Error handling.
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, if in the DB it's without extension...you have to remove it in the same way you did for the (new) name. As side note: do not build SQL commads like that (use parameters), it's pretty unsafe if file name comes from user input.

Comment: Doesn't work :S wait i edit. please tell me what im doing wrong @Adriano

Comment: @JohnSmith what `MessageBox.Show(e.Name + Environment.NewLine + e.OldName);` shows you ?

Comment: Well, to don't guess random you should provide: what variables are and what they contains. How database is and...what "does not work" means (compile time error? no db update? run-time error? something you don't like in data?). I suppose if you log data to provide us enough informatio...you'll see the answer too ;)

Comment: @Prix looool.docx and lol.docx , but im not using e.OldName now in my query? you see in my edit?

Comment: @JohnSmith does your query contain the extension on the file names can you query your database and check that ?

Comment: @Prix when i use the oldfilename it gives me lol without the extension. but the query stil does nothing...

Comment: can you post your querry function ? Also what database are you using ? SQLCompact ? SQL Server ? SQLite ? MySQL ?

Comment: @Prix I have a create function as well and when i create a file, in my database it gives me without extension but when i try rename it just does NOTHING.

Comment: @Prix done it. take a look

Comment: @Prix Wait, now when i create a file and rename it afterwards, it renames every file + i dont want it only to work when i create a file.

Comment: Wrap your MySqlCommand on a try and catch with `MySqlException ex` and see if u get any error message

Comment: @Prix when i pause it i have to create a file again before it renames in the database

Comment: Why would your create file rename files if your query there should use INSERT ? you're not making any sense and I can't see your create code nor have a crystal ball ...

Comment: @Prix i will show the create code... + when i use the try and catch, renaming works only once. After that it does nothing.

Comment: And post the query function you're using on your create as well, I will be back in a few minutes.

Comment: @Prix it's already in it xd

Comment: @Prix Nvm got it working i think.